# How to make pip write a default config file when installing a python package?

Tags: python

I'm packaging an in-house python app. My dir structure is something like:

```
/config
    \-- config.yaml
/app
    \-- ... (python files here...)
```

I've created a MANIFEST.in containing:

```
include config/*.yaml
```

When I extract the tarball created after running `./setup.py sdist`, there are 2 directories, `config` (containing my `config.yaml` file) and `app` containing my package. However, when I `pip install` my app, only the python code is installed in `dist-packages`.

How can I make `pip/setuptools` copy `config/config.yaml` to `/etc/xdg/app/` when I run `pip install app`?

Alternatively how can I at least make the config.yaml file end up somewhere on the filesystem so I can copy it where I want it later (e.g. /usr/share or somewhere - I don't care where it ends up after being installed)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs section [Installing Additional Files Doc](http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-additional-files) suggests:

You can set the relative real path into `data_files`.

```
setup(...,
          data_files=[...,
                      ('/etc/xdg/app/', ['config/config.yaml'])]
     )
```

Obs: "Note that you can specify the directory names where the data files will be installed, but you cannot rename the data files themselves."

Comment: No I hadn't seen that. I'd seen that. The setuptools docs (http://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#non-package-data-files) suggest it's not possible. Thanks!